# Powershell COM Excel visible not working

Tags: excel, powershell, com, visible

I have written a short Powershell script to copy some Excel data.  The script works fine, but it opens Excel every time I run it, even thought the visible property is set to $false. Anyone have any ideas why?  I have searched for answers, but can't find any solutions.  I have also displayed the property and it is set correctly.

Excel opens when the workbook is opened.

Thanks,

Chris J.

Code:

```
## function to close all com objects
function Release-Ref ($ref{
([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$ref)   -gt 0)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
#Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
#####################################################################
## Load excel com objects attach to file
#####################################################################
$ExcelPath = 'C:\Chris_Test.xls'
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $False
write-host "Visible 1"
write-host $Excel.Visible
$ExcelWorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)
$Excel.Visible = $False
write-host "Visible 2"
write-host $Excel.Visible
$ExcelWorkSheet = $Excel.WorkSheets.item("Sheet1")
$Excel.Visible = $False
write-host "Visible 3"
write-host $Excel.Visible
$row = 2
$South_HX_Avg = "This"
$Middle_HX_Avg = " is a "
$North_HX_Avg = "test."
##
## Cells.Item(Row,Column)
#$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($row,1).Value2 = $South_HX_Avg
#$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(2,2).Value2 = $Middle_HX_Avg
#$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(2,3).Value2 = $North_HX_Avg
#####################################################################
# Close connections to Excel
# set interactive to false so no save buttons are shown
#####################################################################
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Excel.ScreenUpdating = $false
$Excel.Visible = $False
write-host "Visible 4"
write-host $Excel.Visible
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.Visible = $False
write-host "Visible 5"
write-host $Excel.Visible
$Excel.UserControl = $false
$Excel.Interactive = $false
## save the workbook
$ExcelWorkBook.Save()
## quit the workbook
$Excel.Quit()
## close all object references
Release-Ref($ExcelWorkSheet)
Release-Ref($ExcelWorkBook)
Release-Ref($Excel)
# Move-Item c:\scripts\test.zip c:\test -force
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting, just to make sure you don't have something stuck in memory that's doing this? That code looks like it should do what you want.

Comment: The Release-Ref function doesn't parse correctly, I think you're missing a closing bracket or brace..

Answer (score 0):

When I uncommented the lines 30,31 and 32, it worked ok, but I had to comment out your calls to Release-Ref (including the definition) for it to parse.

Also, when you create a new Excel object using:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

the visibility of the window is set *by default* to false in the object's constructor, so there's no need to set it explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did try rebooting and also tried it on a different computer with the same results.  Good catch Steve Rathbone, my procedure was missing a parenthesis.  After I fixed it, it still opens Excel.

I also tried commenting out the calls to Release-Ref with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar in a script I've been working with lately. MS Com objects have tons of options in several places.

This works for me.

```
$xlsFile = "\\your\file.xls"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false;
$excel.AskToUpdateLinks = $false;
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($xlsFile, 0, 0, 5, "password")
#do some stuff in excel
$Excel.Quit()
```

PS, you can also set some of the parameters using the workbooks.open() function.

Here's just a few:
Workbooks.Open(FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, Format, Password)

You can read more about com object parameters here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open